# Pyvista question: Why I cannot see my data in result?

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, pyvista

**Background**

I have been using pyvista to visualize 2D image (GPR image) by following [this](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista-support/issues/135) and [this](https://github.com/iannesbitt/readgssi/issues/8#issuecomment-522140504).

**Problem**

I ran the code without any error, but no data was displayed.
[image]

**Data**

Let's assume the stucture of a raw data, (row, column), is (10, 8). One row in the raw data is composed of (X, Y, Z, 5 values) exported from Fortran90 code. X, Y, Z mean coodinates (latitude, longitude, elevation). The values indicate the measurment data. The examplary lines are below.

[38.5, 120.5, 150.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - 1 row

.
.
.

[38.3, 120.3, 150.3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] - 10 row

**Code**

In the script below, after reading the raw data, I separated it into group 1 and group 2. The structure of group 1 is (10, 3) including X, Y, and Z.

Group 1 (Coordinate)

[38.5, 120.5, 150.0] - 1 row

.
.
.

[38.3, 120.3, 150.3] - 10 row

The structure of group 2 is (10, 5) related to the measurment values.

Group 2 (Measurement data)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - 1 row

.
.
.

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9] - 10 row

```
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os
import pandas as pd

cp = os.getcwd()
cp2 = cp + "/data/"


# Load the provided .txt file
with open(cp2 + 'raw_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    txt_content = file.readlines()

data_list = [list(filter(None, line.split())) for line in txt_content]

# Convert the data list to a numpy array
raw_data = np.array(data_list, dtype=float)

# Seperate coordinates and data
cor = raw_data[:,0:3]    # coordinates
data = raw_data[:,3:].T  # measurement data

# Grab the number of rows and columns
nrows, ncols = data.shape 
# Might be opposite for your data, pay attention here
 

# Define the Z spacing of your 2D section
z = 2.0
z_spacing = z / nrows 


# Create structured points draping down from the coordiantes
points = np.repeat(cor, nrows, axis=0)


# repeat the Z locations across
tp = np.arange(0, z_spacing*nrows, z_spacing)
tp = cor[:,2][:,None] - tp
points[:,-1] = tp.ravel()

# Make a StructuredGrid from the structured points
grid = pv.StructuredGrid()
grid.points = points
grid.dimensions = nrows, ncols, 1


# Add the data array - note the ordering!
grid["values"] = data.ravel(order="F")
grid.plot(cmap="seismic", clim=[-1*10**6,1*10**6])
```

Comment: There are too many things going on in your code for us to be able to debug this without a runnable (preferably small) example input. It's very unclear what "path and data" mean, for instance. It's unclear what the actual shape of your various arrays is. The lack of mesh might mean that you are passing inconsistent `dimensions` or similar to your mesh. But again, without being able to run your code we won't be able to help. Please try to [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Thanks, Andras. I edited my question clearly.